# find acceleration of a sky diver

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The velocity $v(t)$ of the sky-diver is described by the differential equation 
$m(dv/dt)=mg−kv$, where m is the mass, g is the gravitational acceleration, k is the air resistance coefficient. At the initial moment $t = 0$ the sky-diver is at rest, $v(0) = 0$.

a) How do I calculate the differential equation for the acceleration $a(t)$, I think I need to differentiate both sides of the equation but I am not sure.

b) Then I am asked to solve the acceleration equation in general form, that is derive a formula for the acceleration versus time.

Comment: you are right about the first part.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you have already is the differential equation involving the acceleration.

You need to separate the variables and integrate:
$$m\int_0^v\frac{1}{mg-kv}dv=\int_0^tdt$$
$$\Rightarrow-\frac mk\left[\ln|mg-kv|\right]_0^v=t$$
$$\Rightarrow\ln\left(\frac{mg-kv}{mg}\right)=-\frac{kt}{m}$$
$$\Rightarrow v=\frac{mg}{k}\left(1-e^{-\frac{kt}{m}}\right)$$

Now you can differentiate to get acceleration as a function of time...

Comment: I think this is one of many particular solution. This is not true answer OP is looking for. To find answer OP seeks, you should find indefinite integral which gives, general solution family. Then by substituting initial conditions, we get solution to system.

Comment: I have used the initial conditions given in the question: $t=0,v=0$

Comment: What i mean is that, we don't always use integral from some initial condition to v. Many books does not bother to explain that and OP may be misleaded by the fact that, every time he needs to integrate from 0 to some variable.